# Code optimization ->Merging two functions in to one function

Tags: python-3.x

its very early days in to programming for me and looking forward to some help with this simple code:

```
import time
start_time       = time.time()
progress_time    = 0
attempts_counter = 0
penetration_time = 2

def force():
    with ISOTPSocket(iface0, SID, DID, basecls=UDS, padding=True) as sock:
            **while progress_time < penetration_time:**
                attempts_counter += 1
                **tempKey = test.random_key(8)** 
                request = UDS()/UDS_SA(securityAccessType=[0x02], securityKey = tempKey)
                response = sock.sr1(request, timeout=0.3, verbose=False)
                print (request,response)
            progress_time  = int(time.time() - start_time)

def Memory():
    with ISOTPSocket(iface0, SID, DID, basecls=UDS, padding=True) as sock:
            **for tempKey in range (0x0F):**
                attempts_counter += 1
                request = UDS()/UDS_SA(securityAccessType=[0x02], securityKey = tempKey)
                response = sock.sr1(request, timeout=0.3, verbose=False)
                print (request,response)
            progress_time  = int(time.time() - start_time)
```

only difference between these two functions are **while**,**for loop** and assigning **tempkey**. so want to merge both in to one function in my class. i tried creating a function for the part of the code after loops then calling it in the loops but didn't work.

Comment: Can you also share the code snippet you tried that didn't run?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
attempts_counter = 1

def process(tempKey, sock):
  attempts_counter += 1
  request = UDS()/UDS_SA(securityAccessType=[0x02], securityKey = tempKey)
  response = sock.sr1(request, timeout=0.3, verbose=False)
  print(request, response)

def force():
    with ISOTPSocket(iface0, SID, DID, basecls=UDS, padding=True) as sock:
            while progress_time < penetration_time:
                tempKey = test.random_key(8)
                process(tempKey, sock)
            progress_time  = int(time.time() - start_time)

def Memory():
    with ISOTPSocket(iface0, SID, DID, basecls=UDS, padding=True) as sock:
            for tempKey in range (0x0F):
                process(tempKey, sock)
            progress_time  = int(time.time() - start_time)
```